# Plotting multiple plots

Tags: matlab, plot, gnuplot, octave

I have some code which I run in Octave (but runs perfectly fine under matlab) that produces plots for me of the physics experiment I'm running. I've decided it would be good if I could produce a few hundred of these plots, by just using my old code but reading in a different datafile each time (I generate these with a different program).

So I took my old code:

```
for u=1:2

f=num2str(u)

xdim=801;
ydim=801;

%ask matlab to create a figure

figure;

filename=strcat('data',f,'.txt')

field=load(filename);

xx=field(:,1); 
yy=field(:,2); 
zz=field(:,3); 

for i=1:xdim
    x1p(i)=xx((i-1)*ydim+1); 
    for j=1:ydim
      z1p(j,i)=(zz((i-1)*ydim+j));
    end
end 


for k=1:ydim
  y1p(k)=yy(k);
end


grid off; 
axis on; 
axis equal; 

%--------------------
% surface plots
%-------------------

surf(x1p,y1p,z1p);

colorbar(); %put a colorbar showing mapping 
                  %between colors and values

title_str=strcat("A map of the Electric Field Strength: m=-5 to 5 eps=100 wa/c=",f)
title(title_str); 
xlabel("x");
ylabel("y"); 

shading interp;   %gives usually best view interpolates between grids
colormap('jet');  %choose the colormap other options hsv,cool,hot e.t.c.

jpg_str=strcat('surf_',f,'.jpg')

print -djpeg jpg_str
end
```

And just put it all in that initial for loop. Unfortunately this errors, returning:

```
multiplot> unset view;
^
line 0: Unrecognized option.  See 'help unset'.
```

I don't know how to fix this problem, as I don't want multiple plots in one image, which is what multiplot seems to be for. How do I go about fixing this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is multiplot coming from? I don't see it, nor have I ever heard of it...

Comment: I don't know about the error you're seeing, but your code will overwrite your plot file. `print -djpeg jpg_str` expands to `print('-djpeg', 'jpg_str')`; you want `print('-djpeg', jpg_str)`.

Comment: I have no idea! It just gives this error. I looked it up though: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/octave/octave_130.html
But that didn't solve my problem one bit. I assume it throws the error simply because I call surf() (which is basically plot()) multiple times, and it still remembers that I did it before. Unfortunately adding "clear;" at the loops end doesn't fix it either.

Comment: Do you know what version of gnuplot octave is working with?

Comment: I fixed it - by calling 'figure(u)' instead of just 'figure'. Thanks for all the help guys!